# Creating a Custom Angular Smart-Table

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, smart-table

a little new here (and new with angular) so go easy on me. I'm attempting to create a nice looking Angular Smart-Table, that has a few specific functions:

- Bootstrap Table
- Search Feature
- Add to Table Feature
- Export in Spreadsheet Pasteable Format
- Dynamic Pie Graph based on Table Data

I am able to create a simple table, but I am having trouble with bootstrap styling and adding the features I mentioned above. If someone could point me in the right direction with how to learn this stuff, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: Haven't really encountered an issue. I just don't know how to approach adding those features to a Smart-Table. Is a Smart-Table even the right option?

Answer (score 0):

Smart-table is a plugin which gives you full control over what and how to display. You may use the table tag if you want, or you may choose to implement the view using a div.

First lets look at a plunker using smart-table: http://plnkr.co/edit/Idbc1JNHKylHuX6mNwZ6?p=preview

```
<table st-set-filter="customFilter" st-table="displayed" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
```

Here you may see the index.html displaying using bootstrap table. Also you may see a basic search feature (firstname and lastname) which comes built in and a couple of complex filters which lets you search using some more advanced rules than just text search.

When it comes to add to table, add a button in bottom to add a row, and use perhaps a modal dialog to input the required values. When saving, make sure you refresh the collection in the controller, there is a 2 way binding, so modifing collection will be reflected in your view.

For export and graphs, reuse the collection in your controller, this is not something which is part of smart-table, you should find different tools to help you with this.

Please note that if retrieving the collection is an asynchronous operation, you need to use the st-safe-src directive, look at the stSafeSrc header here: http://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/#section-basics